# OpenLayers add Marker and Popup

Tags: javascript, html, popup, openlayers, markers

I'm having trouble with OpenLayers. 
My working code is:

```
<html><body>
  <div id="mapdiv"></div>
  <script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
  <script>
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapdiv");
    map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());

    //var results = new OpenLayers.Layer.Text("My Points", { location:"./checkIns_0_view.txt", projection: map.displayProjection});
    //map.addLayer(results);

    var query = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-122.2928337167, 37.5549570333).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject());
    var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
    map.addLayer(markers);
    var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21,25);
    var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
    var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('http://openlayers.org/dev/img/marker-blue.png', size, offset);
    marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(query, icon);
    markers.addMarker(marker);

    var zoom=16;
    map.setCenter (query, zoom);
  </script>
</body></html>
```

Now I want to add a Popup with some informations. I tried using several examples, like http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/osm-marker-popup.html. I want to add something like this:

```
    var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("Popup", query, null, "Text", true);
    map.addPopup(popup);
```

The first line can be compiled, but when I add the second line, the browser doesn't show my map. 
I think it might have to do with the query-lonLat, but I doesn't have the necessary OpenLayers-skills to find out.

I would appreciate an answer very much.

Greetings

Answer (score 2):

1. According [OpenLayers documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.6/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Popup/FramedCloud-js.html#OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud.OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud), you are missing in a popup constructor the *anchor parameter* between *"Text"* and *true*. Probably this is the source of your problem. This parameter has *null* value in the example for a popup:

   ```
   var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("Popup", 
       myLocation.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(), null,
       'We ' +
       'could be here. Or elsewhere.', 
       null,
       true // true if we want a close (X) button, false otherwise
   );
   ```

   In Your case you can to use variable **icon** instead of null value.
2. In function map.addPopup(popup) you should have second parameter **exclusive** as well.
   See OpenLayers documentation dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.addPopup or a definition of this method [here](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Map.js#L1463). I think it is a good practice to use all defined parameters, because it often creates problems.

Hopefully it will work, after adding all parameters.
Your code for a working popup:

```
var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("Popup", query, null, "Text", null, true);
map.addPopup(popup, false);
```

Comment: thank you very much marti jrk for your response. understood, what you mentioned, but it still doesn't work using the additional parameter in 1. and adding false in 2.

Comment: is it relevant at what position in the code i add these two lines?

Comment: @user2513315 yes, it is relevant. You should add popup ( map.addPopup(popup, true); ) after you map.setCenter(); So if you place both of them on the end, it should work.

Comment: thank you very much again. that was my problem. always tried to insert the lines at different positions, but I never dared to insert it at the end, because (why ever) i thought it might be relevant to center the map in the end. thanks!!!